# How to input/type "ー" as in ローマ字 in OSX?

Tags: discussion

Tried many ways and searched on Google but I am unable to input the dash for long vowels in Japanese under OSX.

I am using katakana input mode.

Anyone knows how to do?

Comment: Have you tried a hyphen/dash `-` (which must be somewhere on your keyboard).

Comment: Just found how to solve it. "Hyphen/Dash" is a different character. However, if I press the key right to the "0" number, I get this special character.

Comment: Is this not the same key as the one you press to get the hyphen/dash when you're not in katakana input mode?

Comment: It depends on the keyboard. In hiragana, yes, it is the same key.